Однородные члены предложения и два союза И. Нужна ли запятая?
Город был и остается одним из самых развитых в стране и сегодня является как никогда важным.

Запятые не нужны.
Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом и, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом и с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится.
п.8 по ссылке http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101
